# how to set the query to get the result as below?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to get the result of two rows in two column
my queries are-

```
select tt.* from wp_terms AS tt where tt.terms_id='" . $establishment['term_id'] . "' AND tt.meta_key ='phone';
select tt.* from wp_terms AS tt where tt.terms_id='" . $establishment['term_id'] . "' AND tt.meta_key ='location';
```

each query giving me result as

```
meta_id terms_id    meta_key    meta_value
6926     16         phone      0000 

meta_id terms_id    meta_key    meta_value
6927    16          location    xxx
```

now i want result as

```
meta_id terms_id    meta_value      meta_value1
6926     16        0000          xxx
```

please help
thanks

Comment: Are you asking us how to fetch 2 rows with one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.meta_id, t.terms_id, t.meta_value, tt.metaValue AS meta_value1
FROM wp_terms AS t
INNER JOIN wp_terms AS tt ON t.terms_id = tt.terms_id
   AND t.meta_key = 'phone'
   AND tt.meta_key = 'location'
WHERE t.terms_id='" . $establishment['term_id'] . "'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this.

```
select phone.meta_id, phone.terms_id, phone.meta_value as phone, location.meta_value as location
from
(select tt.* from wp_terms AS tt where tt.terms_id='" . $establishment['term_id'] . "' AND tt.meta_key ='phone') phone,
(select tt.* from wp_terms AS tt where tt.terms_id='" . $establishment['term_id'] . "' AND tt.meta_key ='location') location 
where phone.meta_id = location.meta_id
```